# How to define a data type with an explicit kind quantification?

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, quantifiers, type-kinds

When I define

```hs
data Foo a = Foo [a]
```

then the type is of kind `Foo :: * -> *`.

Having enabled [PolyKinds](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/poly_kinds.html#extension-PolyKinds) and `RankNTypes` I'd like to **explicitly quantify it with a more general kind signature** `Foo :: forall k . k -> k`.

However none of my attempts worked:

```
--    Malformed head of type or class declaration: (Foo :: forall k.
--                                                         k -> k) a
32 | data (Foo :: forall k . k -> k) a = Foo [a]
```

```
-- error: parse error on input ‘::’
32 | data Foo a = Foo [a] :: forall k . k -> k
```

```
-- error:
--     Multiple declarations of ‘Foo’

data Foo :: forall k . k -> k
data Foo a = Foo [a]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [standalone kind signature](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/poly_kinds.html#standalone-kind-signatures-and-polymorphic-recursion):

```
type Foo :: forall k. k -> k
data Foo a = Foo [a]
```

But do note that the kind `forall k. k -> k` is not valid for `Foo`, because `Foo a`, being a data type, must have kind `Type`, furthermore the kind of `[]` is `Type -> Type`. So the kind signature `Foo :: Type -> Type` is forced.

An example that does compile without errors is:

```
type Foo :: forall k. k -> Type
data Foo a = Foo
```

Comment: Thank you, `StandaloneKindSignatures` was what I was missing. (And my actual data type is more complex, I simplified it for the sake of the question.)